# How do I disable multiple chosen keys like CTRL & Caps Lock from boot on DEBIAN 11?

Tags: debian, keyboard

How do I disable multiple chosen keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> & <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> from boot on Debian 11?

Mainly so they can't be used for system commands like opening the terminal or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

[This SuperUser article](https://superuser.com/a/775811/714988) looks like it answers your question - It'll be the same principle

For me on Debian 12 (Bookworm), running `xev -event keyboard` from a terminal :

Pressing down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key shows:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x5ae, subw 0x0, time 2231447, (-655,427), root:(794,709),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

and releasing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key shows:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x5ae, subw 0x0, time 2231560, (-655,427), root:(794,709),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I would then substitute <value> in:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode <value>='
```

with

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 37='
```

For me:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> = 37
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> = 50
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> = 64
- <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> = 66
- <kbd>Win/Command</kbd> = 133

(using the backup method below actually gives you a list of all the mappings if you run it then run `cat ~/originalkeymap.xmod` !)

---

[This other SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/654432/714988) also demonstrates how to reverse it (log out and back in?!) and also back up the existing key map before making any changes - Always a good idea to test!

Backup

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/originalkeymap.xmod
```

Restore

```
xmodmap ~/originalkeymap.xmod
```

You may need to consider what would happen if someone could disconnect and reconnect the keyboard, and also if they attached a second keyboard - I.e. secure your environment.