# How to use setxkbmap to map keys permanently?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xmodmap, setxkbmap

I'm currently using `xmodmap` to remap some keys, keeping my configuration in a `.Xmodmap` file, but every time I boot my laptop, or my screen locks, the customization is lost and I have to run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` once again, even though I set the command to execute on startup and in the `~/.xinitrc` file too.

I've rummaged about forums looking for information on `setxkbmap`, but I can't really understand what's going on, and have trouble trying to remap some keys.

For example, the key on the right of my `Right Alt` key, when pressed under `xev`, looks like this:

> KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
>     root 0x6a8, subw 0x0, time 14892208, (674,389), root:(848,553),
>     state 0x0, keycode 97 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
>     XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>     XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>     XFilterEvent returns: False

1 - So we have `keycode 97` and `keysym NoSymbol`. How would I map that to be `Right Control` using `setxkbmap`?

2 - Also, how can I remap the `Ctrl + Arrow Keys` to work like `Home` / `End` / `PgUp` / `PgDown`?

Most importantly, I want to make these changes **permanent**.

3 - Lastly, is there any comprehensive content or documentation about this program out on the web?

Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.  The following AskUbuntu question has an accepted answer (that references xmodmap) and other answers which have some good feedback, which may answer your question (even if:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-can-i-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04

For your other questions, not using `setxkbmap`, but using `xev` and `xmodmap` , I posted some useful information tonight on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727560/282315 which might answer most of these.

For full documentation, you can type in to a terminal man <PackageName> e.g. `man xmodmap`

As these are SE sites, I'm not going to copy the information to this answer, to keep the original answers in their original question.

---

For the key combinations, you could have a look at Menu >> Keyboard.  There's a 'Shortcuts' section where you can create your own. I'm not sure a Ctrl+Up/Dn can work to do PgUp/PgDn, you might need to look at using macros (like [AutoKey](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764318) `sudo apt install autokey-gtk` - desktop automation utility).  But if you currently have to press a function key to get the PageUp (e.g. Fn+Up), there should be a Function Lock key to reverse the functions if you use them all the time, it could be a padlock that you Fn+Lock and it switches them around.

Comment: Autokey is usually great for things like this, but I don't think it will accept the arrow keys as part of hotkey/shortcut. I gave that a quick try and it didn't work. If you're determined to pursue this, take a look at [interception-tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Interception-tools). Maybe that would work.